# Codeigniter + HMVC + REST

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, rest, hmvc

I'm working on Codeigniter + HMVC based application and I'm trying to add a new module. I use Phil Sturgeon's **REST_Controller 2.6.0** and **Format** libraries to create an REST API as a module.

When I try to get for example http://api.example.com/user/id/1/ or http://api.example.com/user/id/1/format/json I gеt the below error:

```
 A PHP Error was encountered
 Severity: Notice
 Message: Undefined property: Api::$format
 Filename: libraries/REST_Controller.php
 Line Number: 380
```

In my **routes.php** I have this:

```
 $route['user/id/(:num)/format/(:any)'] = "api/user/$1/format/$2";
 $route['user/id/(:num)'] = "api/user/$1";
```

The directory structure of the application is:

```
application
--modules
----api
------config
------controller
```

Finlay, I use the default configurations and I didn't change anything. The Format library is auto loaded in **autoload.php**. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, can you share how did you implement rest api with hmvc? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change Rest_Controller to extend HMVC's MX_Controller rather than CI_Controller.

Comment: Thanks Tjkoopa! The problem is fixed!

Comment: hey can i ask where to find a tutorial on setting up rest on hmvc? or maybe can you please help me? thanks

Comment: @kev_m there is nothing specific you need to do. Just import MX library and follow the steps.