# SETTING UP code igniter hmvc with Phil Sturgeon's REST_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

i have a project, where it is a pure php. It is in an hmvc format, now, i want to rework it to be a RESTful one. i have seen videos, and it is only mvc, i am trying to do is

`abstract class REST_Controller extends MY_Controller`

and

`class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {`

and finally my controller will be

`class Api extends REST_Controller {`

but i saw this link

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430118/codeigniter-hmvc-rest` that says

The directory structure of the application is:

```
application
--modules
----api
------config
------controller
```

can anyone help me set up hmvc to have Phil Sturgeon's REST_Controller or can anyone give me a tutorial or something for this.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814

Comment: that ones in mvc. i am trying to work on hmvc

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: REST_Controller extend MX_Controller

Comment: is the set up on mvc for example, in mvc, i put rest_controller and format.php in library, is it the sane setup in hmvc ? but ill just do `REST_Controller extend MX_Controller`